# What is the order of form/report events in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, events

What is the order of events for forms, reports, and subforms in MS Access?

Comment: The reason I voted to close this very old question is that I don't see a way to improve the accepted, link-only answer apart from copy/pasting the entire contents of the linked support article, and that would serve no practical purpose. So this seems too broad by current standards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This article describes the [Order of events for forms and subforms](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm3) in MS Access, as does this one: [Form Events](http://www.simply-access.com/Form-Events.html).

One of the best references for MS Access programming is this book: [Access 2002 Desktop Developer's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782140092). My Access 97 version has a detailed description of Access's Event Model.

Comment: The help file outlines it all pretty well. In A2003, search the Access help for "form event order" and the first item that comes up is "Order of events for database objects". This is the exact same content (so far as I can tell) as in the first URL cited above.

Comment: The URL for the form events link has changed. I can't edit the answer since the change is only one character. Here's the new link: http://www.simply-access.com/Form-Events.html

Comment: Hi @MitchWheat out of date links

Comment: Feel free to update them if you have fresher ones...It was answered 5 years ago....

Comment: Mostly I find that I get flagged as not an answer, I thought I was being polite :)

Comment: I found some current links. My edit description refers to an [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249049.aspx) but I think the Office support article is better and can't update the edit description without something else to edit. :) cc @Fionnuala re: your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10818904/3). If either of you have other answers that point to this page I haven't seen them.

Comment: okay...so does a Control/Field's BeforeUpdate occur before or after that for a Form (also AfterUpdate, etc)?  At which point does Control.Value get copied to Control.OldValue and replaced with a new value? So many questions that don't seem to be answered by the `Order of events for forms and subforms` link.